# Insert values in table for all distinct value of certain column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table structure like this

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Apple | sweet |
| 4 | Mango | sweet |
| 4 | Apple | sour |
| 3 | Mango | sweet |
| 3 | Grapes | sweet |
| 4 | Grapes | sweet |

I want to insert a row for all distinct Column1 value, where other two column value remains same.

Like if i have to insert value Banana,sweet. It should be inserted for all distinct column 1 value at once.

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: You will have no answer with a question like this. Please keep in mind that people that may answer are doing it from their own time for free. So at least make the effort to write your question properly.

Comment: I wrote it in proper format, but after submission it got distorted.

Comment: So, if you insert a banana, how does the result look like? How many rows do you expect to get? Two? Four? Something else? Which ones?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table_name (col1, col2, col3)
  select distinct col1, 'Banana', 'sweet' from table_name
;
```

Replace `table_name` with the actual table name, and `col1, col2, col3` with the actual column names.

Note that this will add rows even if `'Banana', 'sweet'` already exists in the table for some of the `col1` values. If you don't want that, then (1) you should have mentioned that in your question, and (2) it can be fixed easily, with a `where` clause.